# Exception thrown while importing macros using Configuration.addAutoImport()

Tags: freemarker

**editable.ftl**

```
[#ftl]
[#macro editable field ]
   [#if field??]
        [#if isEditable]
            <h:inputext value="${field}" />
        [#else]
            ${field?eval}
        [/#if]
    [/#if]
[/#macro]
```

what is the right way to import this to my templates. i tried with **cfg.addAutoImport("me", "editable.ftl")**.
and following exception is thrown when i tried to process my main Template.

ERROR [freemarker.runtime] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error executing FreeMarker template: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> field  [in template "editable" at line 5, column 30]

Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use [#if myOptionalVar??]when-present[#else]when-missing[/#if]. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)??

The failing instruction:
==> ${field}  [in template "editable" at line 5, column 28]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:98) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:382) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:115) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:93) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1712) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.importLib(Environment.java:1784) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.importLib(Environment.java:1733) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.doAutoImportsAndIncludes(Configuration.java:1105) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Configurable.doAutoImportsAndIncludes(Configurable.java:1271) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Configurable.doAutoImportsAndIncludes(Configurable.java:1271) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:242) [freemarker-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]

**The macros code should be executed when invoked but here seems they are invoked during import. Is it treated here really a macro? Please guide me what is wrong with this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros aren't executed when importing (of course, unless you call them in the imported FTL itself outside a macro). This looks like an issue with the tag syntax selection. If FTL doesn't switch to `[#...]` tag syntax from the default `<#...>` tag syntax, then the only non-static-text parts will be the `${...}`-s, and hence `field` won't be defined in your case. So the question is why it doesn't switch when you start the template with `[#ftl]`. Maybe you have an invisible BOM at the beginning of the file (Windows Notepad for example adds a BOM when editing UTF-8 files), or something else before the `[#ftl]`.

BTW, setting `tag_syntax` to `auto_detect` prevents such surprises. It's not the default  for backward compatibility...

Comment: Thanks, seems there was some issue with invisible characters. I recreated the file and now it is gone.